# How to export data from a Puppeteer script?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

So, I got this script that collects titles from a news website.
The result of the scraping is pushed into the x empty array.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
export let x = []
async function scrapeNewsTitles(url){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

   
    const [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/main/div[1]/div[1]/article/figure/a/img');
    const src = await el.getProperty('src');
    const srcTxt = await src.jsonValue();
    console.log(srcTxt);
    const [el2] = await page.$x('/html/body/main/div[1]/div[1]/article/div/h1/a');
    const txt = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();

    const newArticle = {srcTxt, rawTxt};
    x.push(newArticle);

    browser.close();

    console.log(x)
}

scrapeNewsTitles('https://www.lmneuquen.com');
```

What I want now is to export the x array, which contains the collected data, so I can use it in another script. The problem is that if I do this...

> export let x = []

and then I import it into another file like this...

> import {x} from './file.js'

...it gives me the following error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Would you point me in the right direction to do it?

Thank you in advance! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "export let x = []", use "module.exports".

So, change your code to:

```
let x = []
```

and at the end of the code, write

```
module.exports = {"x": x};
```

When you import this array from the new file, use

```
let x = require("./index.js") //Instead of index.js, write the name of your first file.
console.log(x);
```

The reason why is that the keywords "export" and "import from" are used in Vanilla JS. However, the code that you are using is Node JS, so the structure will be slightly different.

Comment: Now I'm able to use that variable in another file. Thank you very much, SatvikVejendla!

Comment: mcd-user: Perhaps to thank @SatvikVejendla you can accept his answer as the answer to your question?